# Is it guaranteed that sizeof(std::atomic<integer type>) == sizeof(integer type)?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

In other words, is `std::atomic<int>` guaranteed to hold only a single `int` value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No.**

Per Paragraph 29.5/9 of the C++11 Standard:

> [ Note: The representation of an atomic specialization need not have the same size as its corresponding
>   argument type. Specializations should have the same size whenever possible, as this reduces the effort
>   required to port existing code. —end note ]